# how to remove the word which is not the name of person

Tags: python, nltk

I want to get the name of person from text file  i use the nltk it returns name as well as the word which is not name:

```
def extract_names(text):
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)
    pos = pos_tag(tokens)
    sentt = ne_chunk(pos, binary = False)
    person_list = []
    person = []
    name = ""
    for subtree in sentt.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'PERSON'):
        for leaf in subtree.leaves():
            person.append(leaf[0])
        if len(person) > 1: #avoid grabbing lone surnames
            for part in person:
                name += part + ' '
            name = remove_useless_name(name)
            if name[:-1] not in person_list:
                person_list.append(name[:-1])
            name = ''
        person = []

    return person_list
```

i want to remove that word which is not name which method should i use for removing the word.
Input like

```
"Sunder Pichai"
"View Profile"
"Risk Management"
```

sample output:

```
"Sunder Pichai"
```

Comment: Once i think to create a csv file for useless name like "View Profile", "Risk Management" and so on and after the comapre and remove but it is not solution at all because i don't know what result it gives. Any one can help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

NLTK provides the corpora of the most common English words (`nltk.corpus.words.words('en')`) and most common English names (`nltk.corpus.names.words()`). Unfortunately, the latter one would not have 
*Sunder* or *Pichai*, so you have to rely on the former. Unfortunately again, there are names that are also common English words (e.g., *Hope*), which makes the task even more challenging. You can still automate it to some extent:

```
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words('en'))

def isname1(string):
    return any([w not in words for w in string.lower().split()])

def isname2(string):
    return all([w not in words for w in string.lower().split()])

list(map(isname1, ["Sunder Pichai", "View Profile", "Risk Management"]))
#[True, False, False]
list(map(isname2, ["Sunder Pichai", "View Profile", "Risk Management"]))
#[False, False, False]
```

As you can see, the second function is more aggressive and does not recognize "Sunder Pichai" as a name (because "sunder" is actually an English word).

Comment: Thanks DvZ but it also gives the True value for " View Profile Gargi Kaul Joint"," Profile Ms"

Comment: `isname1` does, `isname2` does not. As I have said above, there is no ironclad way of telling whether something is a name or not. Many words can be used both as names and as general nouns.

Comment: If i try with isname2 it gives also False for "Suner Pichai" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a dictionary, and check whether all parts of the name is a real word and/or surname is a known name

Comment: Is there any inbuilt Dictionary is available for checking real name

Comment: See DyZ's answer, he provides an example code which resides on my idea.